# why i am getting jenkins seed job commit changes in automated job for my micro services

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am able to create new jobs for each of my micro services with the help of jenkins seed job.

when i try to build my micro services specific job i am able to see changes(commits) made for my seed job as well

Comment: Could you please provide some more information, like the logs, Jenkinsfile. snapshots etc..